# Moving an iterator while in a stl algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to move forward (or backwards) while in a loop

For example

```
vector<int> s{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
for_each(begin(s), end(s), []() {
    if(....) // Some logic that moves the iterator forward 2 spaces
    {
        next(s); 
    }
    else {
         // Normal processing
    }
});
```

of course the regular for loops does the same thing but I want to avoid it if I can.

```
for(auto i = 0UL; i < size();) {
    i+=2; 
}
```

Comment: if you increment the iterator, then it isnt really a `for_each` and imho a plain loop is more clear whenever you manipulate the index like this

Answer (score 4):

There's no portable way of, in a sense, intercepting the iteration in `std::for_each`.

But you could handle the iteration yourself if you really can't stomach the (superior?) way of using a regular `for` loop with a `std::size_t`.

```
for (auto/*ToDo - perhaps & here*/ it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
    // You can advance `it` with `++it` and retard it with `--it`.
}
```

Comment: My specific use case is that: In the `for` loop I have an recursive function that consumes items (something like a lexer), so my intention is to std::accumulate against the input but not always a single value. I generally agree, in this case, the naïve for loop is fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't interact with the iterators with `std::for_each`, by the time control reaches your `UnaryFunction` they have been dereferenced.

You could close over a "skip now" variable with your lambda, and test that for an early return.

e.g.

```
int skip_count = 0;
vector<int> s{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
for_each(begin(s), end(s), [&skip_count]() {
    if(skip_count) 
    {
        --skip_count;
        return;
    }
    else if ( /* Some test */ ) {
         skip_count = 2;
    }
    else {
         // Normal processing
    }
});
```